# What is the purpose of class template parameter Proj and class template IndirectUnaryPredicate in the ranges TS?

Tags: c++, c++-ts

[Cpp-reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/algorithm/all_any_none_of) shows the following function template (among others) from the (experimental) ranges TS:

```
template< ranges::InputIterator I, ranges::Sentinel<I> S,
   class Proj = ranges::identity,
   ranges::IndirectUnaryPredicate<ranges::projected<I, Proj>> Pred >
bool all_of( I first, S last, Pred pred, Proj proj = Proj{} );
```

What can the template parameter `Proj` used for in combination with `IndirectUnaryPredicate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a projection. You can use it to "project" the elements of the range before passing them to the predicate. It is useful, for example, when you are going to apply predicate to a complex datatype like `std::pair`, let's we want to apply predicate to the `std::pair::second`.

```
all_of(range_of_std_pairs, pred, &pair_t::second);
```

checks a range of std::pairs using predicate `pred` on the pair's second element.